# How to hide a .php, .html or .text file from an external web user

Tags: php

If  I open my URL http://example.com/, it shows my all sub directory like below

```
Index of /
•   data1.php 
•   data1.txt
```

I want if any web user search like  “http://example.com”, it will automatically forwarded the like http://example.com/data1.php. By this way I want to hide my all php, html or .text  file form external web user.

Comment: You need to configure your web server.

Comment: You can disallow directly listings on your web server.  Additionally, you can create a default page that will load in place of a directory listing.  As for "hiding" your files, understand that if you make them inaccessible then, well, people won't be able to access them.

Comment: you could just rename data1.php to index.php

Comment: somehow I feel that telling you `Options -Indexes` wont be much of a help. As SLaks already stated, you need to configure your webserver. If its apache or iis or whatsoever, have a read into those options. Everything you want can be achieved with really tiny effort

Comment: @phpNoOb `.htaccess` is one way of configuring the web server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hide index.php or index.html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1288678/hide-index-php-or-index-html-of-an-url)

Comment: Hi david, i am very new in this area, your comment "you can create a default page",how to do this, if posible then let me know the code.in that page i will be showing link http://example.com/data1.php.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to have a `.htaccess` file in the web root and just keep this as the first line

```
DirectoryIndex home.php
```

Also you can make changes in the your `httpd.conf` file

```
<IfModule dir_module>  #Keep adding pages here, it will read from left to right
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.php3 index.html index.htm
</IfModule>
```

but you better stick to `.htaccess` instead

---

Not required but you might also like to deny directory listing you can use this

```
#Block Directory Listing
IndexIgnore *
```

Comment: @nur2544 you welcome, if this has helped you, than mark the answer as correct :)

Comment: How can I test this? How can I try to access the files via browser?

Answer (score 0):

If you have permission to edit the master configuration files

Edit the files httpd.conf and srm.conf file and do the following:

- Find this line.

  ```
  DirectoryIndex index.html
  ```
- Change it as follows:

  ```
  DirectoryIndex index.shtml index.html
  ```

Of course, you can use any filename you wish. I prefer to leave index.html as a valid index as well.

Changing The Default Page using .htaccess

If you are unable to edit your master configuration files, you can use this directive from .htaccess. Just edit the .htaccess file located in your main HTML directory. If you do not have this file, feel free to create it!

To change the default page, either edit the existing DirectoryIndex line or add the following:

```
DirectoryIndex index.shtml index.html
```

This will make index.shtml the default page.

By using a .htaccess file in a subdirectory, you can specify a different default page for that one directory without affecting the rest of your site.

Font: http://bignosebird.com/apache/a2.shtml

Comment: Hi Oswald, thanks for reply. i got your point, i will try to resolve my issue as you told.