# Redirect /index.php - wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I want that if someone got link to my site, lets say: www.bla.com/index.php , he will redirect to www.bla.com. or in another words - remove the index.php.

Here is my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^bla\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.bla.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Either if someone got link: www.bla.com/camera/index.php - it will redirect to www.bla.com/camera/.

For now, the site itself works great, without index.php, but i want to remove the index.php if someone came from extern link.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1288678/hide-index-php-or-index-html-of-an-url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This post is tagged with WordPress. All of what you're looking for and doing (canonical domain, canonical url without `index.php`) has been built into WordPress at least since WP 3.0 when permalinks are turned on... Look into [canonical redirects](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/canonical.php) -- you'll find the logic in there.

Comment: The posts works great, without index.php. what i want - that if i give you link to my site, for example: bla.com/index.php - you will redirect to bla.com

Comment: That works already unless you've messed around with rewrite rules and canonical redirects... Have you tried? :-)

Comment: The SEO man evidently doesn't know much WordPress, or (if I may add) of what he's talking about for that matter (since WP also publishes canonical urls as a meta tag, rendering the point completely moot). :-)

Comment: Ok, so i think you helped me !

Comment: As an aside, if he advised you to use `/%postname%/` or something to that order as your site's permalink, you're setting yourself up for enormous performance problems (and crippled SEO) if you start adding more than a few static pages. If he did, ignore him and select the default date/name based rule, which performs fine, offers better UI, and doesn't trigger verbose rewrite rules in WP.

Answer (score 2):

try like that in

```
.htaccess
```

---

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^bla\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.bla.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^index.php/(.*)$ /$1 [R=302,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the OP wants to prevent using index.php even when external links are involved. After following the advice from the other question. Try this.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index.php$ http://www.bla.com/$1/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thank you. You understand my question, i try this line but it still have the index.php.

Answer (score 0):

With this code, you will be returned to the index.php page:

```
wp_redirect( home_url() );
exit;
```

[image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).